# jqGrid treegrid addJSONData append new data to old data after opening any node

Tags: jqgrid, treenode, treegrid

I have a treeGrid in jqgrid, using local data to to populate the tree. And the method I use to call new data to the tree is done by calling addJSONData.

The tree data will be refreshed based on a certain function, such as in my case when a dropdownlist value gets changed, the treeGrid will repaint.

At this point, everything worked perfectly, I could reload new data to the tree nicely. 
Here comes the issue, when I open a treeGrid's node, once I open the node, even after closing it, by reloading the data, it will APPEND to the old data instead of loading a whole new data array inside.

under mygrid[0].addJSONData(mydata), looking into mygrid[0].rows it gave HTMLCollection[7], which row ONE was the header, 6 rows are data; Now after opening a node, and reloading, it didn't clear the data, but append to the existing one - mygrid[0].rows became HTMLCollection[13].

```
    mygrid.jqGrid({
                        datatype: "jsonstring",                   
                        datastr: mydata,
                        colNames: gridColName, 
                        colModel: colMol,
                        height: '100%',
                        rowNum: 10000,
                        sortname: keyFieldName,
                        treeGrid: true,
                        treeGridModel: 'adjacency', //'nested',                       
                        ExpandColumn: keyFieldName,
                        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                        onSelectRow: function (id) {                        
                            var selectedRow = $(this).getLocalRow(id);
                            if (clickModel !== 'Bottom Level'){
                                ModifyClassificationByRow(selectedRow);
                            } else { //update values only if NOT BottomLevel
                                var parentVal = selectedRow[parentName];
                                if (output.DataLibData.Data.DeepestLevel === parentVal){
                                    ModifyClassificationByRow(selectedRow);
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    });
mygrid[0].addJSONData(mydata);
```

I tried different something else such as `mygrid.jqGrid('clearGridData');` to clear the data before addJSONData, but this empty the whole grid and return nothing even there were data inside mydata, yes under condition when nodes are opened up or touched before.

Could someone please verify this is a bug/ another way to work around?